# How do I call #name from a different page

Tags: html

I have a nav-bar and it has 2 tabs (#aboutus and #contactus). Clicking on them populates information on the same page.

When I try to call the #contactus from the different page, I used
`<a href="../path/index.html#contactus"` and it doesn't work.

Also, when I hover my mouse over #contactus, I could see its index.html#contactus at the bottom of my screen and not in URL.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: *"Clicking on them populates information on the same page."* - Can you elaborate on this functionality?  Are these links simply *navigating* somewhere on the page using only HTML?  Or is some JavaScript functionality being invoked?  Or something else?

Comment: please show us your code that we can help you somehow

Comment: I have 2 html pages. index.html and page2.html. 
index.html has a nav bar which has 2 tabs #contactus and #aboutus. Clicking on these tabs displays a table on the same page (index.html)

From page2.html, when I use <a href = "../path/index.html#contactus", it doestnt displays the content of #contactus. It just loads index.html

Comment: and its a plain html and no JS has been used